# How to load more items when we scroll down like in google places

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to load more items when we scroll down like in  google places

http://www.google.com/city/portland/

When we scroll it has load items

Comment: you should start from somewhere, for example, you want to use Ajax loading on a grid while scrolling? you should then try to detect page or grid scrolling event client side with JQuery (or other library you like to use) then load more data and inject it into the page (or grid) again with JQuery. Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

I find [this](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/) page to have an excellent example of a simple scroll-loading mechanism that is easy to understand for beginners, complete with a demo so you can see things working. If you would like to debug the demo's jscript use firefox and its plugin firebug or use Google Chrome's built-in debugger.